# Where are VS/TFS 2010 DIFF options at?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm newish to TFS and am working with VS and TFS 2010 RC releases. In every other DIFF tool I've used in the past I have had options for configuring how to treat whitespace differences, among other things. Where are these options when working with VS2010 and TFS2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best choice when using the compare features in VSTS is to plug in your favorite 3rd party compare tool. Like, Beyond Compare, Araxis Merge, whatever. Then these settings are much more natural to you if you are familiar with the product.

Comment: Interesting... I'll look into this as a work-around. Are there absolutely no settings for the VSTS DIFF tool, though? I cannot find a *single* option for it.

Comment: I would add 'SourceGear' diffmerge to that list. Unlike those other suggestions you can use DiffMerge for free. (And it doesn't show a unix heritage like most open source diff/merge tools)

Comment: We actually are migrating from Fortress to TFS so I'm quite familiar with DiffMerge. I was planning on initially trying it out with that anyways - funny coincidence. :-)

Comment: @Jax...I was also never able to find them...sorry

Answer (score 3):

I have found these two blog posts to be immensely helpful. I have integrated DiffMerge as my Diff tool and it integrates perfectly using the settings from James Manning's blog post.

- [James Manning with Integration Settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx)
- [Buck Hodge's higher-level post with other useful links](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/03/09/configure-diff-merge.aspx)

For DiffMerge, the parameters I used were:

```
/title1=%6 /title2=%7 %1 %2
```