# Open two different source versions simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In instance 1 of Visual Studio I want to open the latest version of my source. In instance 2 of VS I want to open a previous version. How can I do this?

I tried opening two instances of VS and just pulling it, but since they both point to the same directory "C:\Source\ProjectName", I end up just overwriting one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating another [workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753.aspx) and map it to a different file directory. Then have your original workspace open in VS #1 and the new workspace open in VS #2

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't you just either branch or make copy of the solution to a separate folder on disk? That's what I would do (in fact, branching in TFS is specifically what we do for these sorts of situations).

[edit]
I'm assuming that the `Compare` feature is not what you're looking for? If so, there are fairly simple ways to [enhance the default functionality there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524346/where-are-vs-tfs-2010-diff-options-at), such as using DiffMerge.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I think either way will work.  In my case, this is just a temporary division of code with no merging involved (its far too complex to merge as the fundamental communication between pages died, I need to re-write) so maybe a workspace is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to have two versions of the file open in two different VS instances, you will have to create an additional workspace that points to the same repository and use "get specific version" on the file you want.

Then you can have one instance of VS open with the latest version and the other instance open with the specific version.

You can learn how to create a new workspace [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384(v=VS.90).aspx) if you don't already know.

Comment: I need to explore the older code via the debugger.  I just converted to master pages and the old forms methods of passing data between pages completely broke.  I have to figure out how the old way functioned in order to re-write it to work with master pages.

Comment: I see.  If that is the case, then creating a new workspace and getting a previous version (in your case pre-master pages) should work just fine.